# Smooth fade in/out in jQuery is possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fade

I have few image backgrounds (1650x1050px) and they are fading smooth only in Safari & Opera. Firefox, Chrome and IE7/8 you can see "frames" of fade like taking pictures.
I'm using jQuery 1.4.4 and Supersized 3.0 plugin modified by me (before modification animation also wasn't smooth enough)

Any ideas? Should i try other library or/and plugin?

Comment: I assume, it's the browsers. You could check that with IE9 and FF4 (both beta), because AFAIK they have rendering accelerated by using the GPU.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Boldewyn. It wont be your code that is the problem, it will be the browsers struggling to render the large images you are animating. I heard somewhere that MooTools had smoother animations so you could try that. Never tried it myself though.

But most likely the results will be the same.

W.

Answer (score 0):

As you are telling that you are rendering large images so **vertical scroller** in the browser might be affecting the animations.

May be the reason just sharing my experience with you.

Before tried to Google this out but was unsuccessful.

With regards,
Wasim